# Estimating the Riemann integral of $f$ using an upper bound for $f$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

> Show is that the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is bounded by $M(b-a)$, where $M$ is a bound of $f(x)$.

I was thinking I would show that $M(b-a)$ is larger than every Riemann sum, but my proof includes the phrase "choose a tagged partition  such that the absolute value of the associated Riemann sum is larger than the absolute of the integral. But I don't know if this is always possible.

Can you give me a hint as to how to show this, if it is possible? I need it for a homework problem I'm working on, and I'm technically not supposed to know about the Upper Riemann sum of a function, although I've already gone through the trouble of defining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Take the Riemann sum where the partitioning of $[a,b]$ is simply $\{[a,b]\}$ (in other words, $x_0=a, x_1=b$), and pick the element from $[a,b]$ for which the Riemann sum will be large enough.

---

EDIT:

To prove that the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is bounded by $M(b-a)$, where $M$ is a bound for $f$, it is enough to show that for **every** Riemann sum $S$, you have $S<M(b-a)$ (since if it is true for every Riemann sum, it must be true for their limit as well).

This is fairly simple, since for some $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n=b$ and $x_k^*\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$ for $k=1,2\dots, n$, you know that
$$S=(x_1-x_0)f(x_1^*) + (x_2-x_1)f(x_2^*) + \cdots + (x_n-x_{n-1})f(x_n^*)$$

Now, use the fact that for every $k$, you have $f(x_k^*)<M$. What equality do you get?

Comment: Sadly, this is the result I'm trying to prove.

Comment: @ZacharyF No, the result you are trying to prove that there exists some Riemann sum greater than the integral. My hint is that you should only look at the simplest possible Riemann sum, where $a=x_0<x_1=b$.

Comment: What I mean is, the actual homework problem is to show that the integral is bounded by M(b-a)

Comment: You just need to show that there must be some $x$ such that $f(x)(b-a) \ge \int_a^b f$.

Comment: It is easier to show that if $f \le g$ then $\int f \le \int g$. Then use $g = M$.

Comment: @copper.hat do you think I could get there from the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @ZacharyF  See my edit.

Comment: @ZacharyF: That is overkill in this case. It follows from the Riemann sum directly. The way to show it is to show that if $\phi \ge 0$ then any Riemann sum must also be positive.

Comment: @copper.hat could you explain what phi is? I'm operating on about an hour of sleep.

Comment: @5xum's answer is the most direct here. I was just pointing out that to prove that if $f \le g$ then $\int f \le \int g$, start by letting $\phi =g-f$ and showing $\int \phi \ge 0$.